# Fitting table to column generated from external file (.eps)

Tags: tables, two-column, width, elsarticle, embedding

I want to know how to fit table column to page from external file with "EPS" format.

I'm writing manuscript for [Science of the Total Environment](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/science-of-the-total-environment/0048-9697/guide-for-authors) which uses two column `elsarticle` format.
In author's guide (above link),
there were unusual clauses about including tables in manuscript.

> Tables should never be included within the text, because file(s) containing tables are attached separately in the electronic submission system.

> Please submit Figures and Tables in separate files in an approved format (TIFF, EPS or MS Office files) with the correct resolution.

Embedding table in separate files is ok, but restricting format limited to TIFF, EPS, or MS Office files is hard to understand.

Despite of that, I figured out how to include table in this journal's manuscript.

1. Create another .tex file (named as `ext-tb.tex`)using `standalone` package.
2. Use `tabular` package to create table.
3. Compile `ext-tb.tex` and generate `ext-tb.eps'
4. In manuscript file (named as `main.tex`), treat table as graphics by using `\includegraphics`

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Table from EPS format}
\label{tab:ext-tb}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/ext-tb.eps}
\end{table*}
```

However, I couldn't manage how to stretch table to `columnwidth` or `textwidth` of journal. When I read other papers from this journal, I found that tables are fit to its `columnwidth` or `textwidth`.

- In external files, it was impossible to know `columnwidth` or `textwidth` of `elsarticle` and they was differed by `documentclass` options. I couldn't adjust table column size even with `tabularx`
- In manuscript files, I used `table` to add captions and footnote, however I couldn't modify table's column width because table is treated as figure.
- `resizebox` wasn't helpful because it enlarges font size of table.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Change your workflow

 (1) Start making a draft of the complete paper until your "final" version.
 
 (2) Prepare a new  only-text document to send
 
 (3) Prepare  separate files for each table  using the same class and preamble of the main document. Compile and generate the `.eps` to send  
 
 (4) The published article will likely be different from your draft because the editors will place tables and figures as they please.

Comment: Yeah, that seems the only way not to trouble with `\columnwidth` and `\textwidth`. I will try that.